# Constant loss through epochs

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I code this neural network to make a gaussian regression but I don't understand why my loss doesn't change through epochs. I set the learning rate to 1 to see the loss decreases but it does not. I chose to take 2000 poitns to train my Neural network. I watched several algorithms on this website and I don't really understand why my algorithm do not achieve what I expect.
I have already imported all libraries needed.

Thank you for your help

```
def f(x):
    return x * np.sin(x) # function to predict


m =2000 
X_bis = np.zeros((1,m),dtype = float)
X_bis=np.random.random(m)*10

        ## Create my training,validation and test set

X_train = X_bis[0:600]
X_val = X_bis[600:800]
X_test = X_bis[800:]

y_train = f(X_train) 
y_val = f(X_val)
y_test = f(X_test)
    
mean_X_train = np.mean(X_train)
std_X_train = np.std(X_train)

mean_y_train = np.mean(y_train)
std_y_train =np.std(y_train)


class MyDataset(data.Dataset):

    def __init__(self, data_feature, data_target):
        self.data_feature = data_feature
        self.data_target = data_target
       
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data_feature)
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        X_train_normalized = (self.data_feature[index] - mean_X_train) / std_X_train
        y_train_normalized = (self.data_target[index] - mean_y_train) / std_y_train
        return torch.from_numpy(np.array(X_train_normalized,ndmin=1)).float(), torch.from_numpy(np.array(y_train_normalized, ndmin = 1)).float()
                    
  
training_set  = MyDataset(X_train,y_train) 
train_loading = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(training_set, batch_size= 100)
    
val_set = MyDataset(X_val, y_val)  
val_loading = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_set, batch_size= 10)
    
test_set  = MyDataset(X_test,y_test) 
test_loading = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_set, batch_size= 100)


class Net(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Net, self).__init__()
    self.FC1 = nn.Linear(1,10)
    self.FC2 = nn.Linear(10, 1)
  def forward(self, x):
    x = F.relu(self.FC1(x)) 
    x = self.FC2(x)
    return x

model = Net()

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(),
lr=1, weight_decay= 0.01, momentum = 0.9)



def train(net, train_loader, optimizer, epoch):
    net.train()
    total_loss=0
    for idx,(data, target) in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
        outputs = net(data)
        loss = criterion(outputs,target)
        total_loss +=loss.cpu().item()
        optimizer.step()
    print('Epoch:', epoch , 'average training loss ', total_loss/ len(train_loader))


def test(net,test_loader):
    net.eval()
    total_loss = 0
    for idx,(data, target) in enumerate(test_loader,0):
        outputs = net(data)
        outputs = outputs * std_X_train + mean_X_train
        target = target * std_y_train + mean_y_train
        loss = criterion(outputs,target)
        total_loss += sqrt(loss.cpu().item())
    print('average testing loss', total_loss/len(test_loader))
    
        
for epoch in range(50): 
    train(model,train_loading,optimizer,epoch)
    test(model,val_loading)    

'''
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering why you don't have `loss.backward()` after the line that you compute the loss (i.e., `loss = criterion(outputs,target)`) in your training snippet. This will help backpropagating and ultimately updating the parameters of your network upon `optimizer.step()`. Also, try using lower learning rates as `lr=1` normally is too much in training such networks. Try using learning rates in between 0.001-0.01 to see if your network is learning the mapping between input X and target Y.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! it works better now but my loss keeps increasing so I decreased the learning rate to 0.0001. It seems very small for me so do you think it migth have another problem I have not seen yet ?

Comment: Try experimenting with Optimizers such as Adam which is shown to be the most effective one, with different learning rates (not just one, or two). These are the hyperparameters that highly correspond with your task, and data; and you will have to play around to find the optimal ones. @MrCurcuma